# print one by one itreation of loop instead of at once using php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, counter

I m trying to print out loop iteration one by one instead of one using ajax is this possible?
Like
iteration 1
iteration 2

etc but they should not at once but one by one as the loop work

Here is my ajax and php code.At this moment the whole code process and finally gives output instead of one by one

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("button").click(function(){

  $.ajax({url:"counter.php",success:function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
});


});
</script>
<button name="button" value="button" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
```

Here is PHP code

```
<?php

     for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
     {
       echo "<div>" . time() . ": Iteration $i</div>";
       sleep(1);

       flush();
     } 

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to once you post a request loop get the response and revert the response to ajax method 
loop execute so fast , you need to sleep the loop once it execute so time, so that once you got a result after some second again loop execute and you got again a response

please follow this timeout function to sleep loop for a while

Where i belong the param you pass throughout the loop and not lost the dynamic value....

```
> (function(i){
>         setTimeout(function(){
> 
> }, 1000 * i);
>     }(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's true. PHP will (by default) send the output if the full PHP script is executed. If you want a counter you should loop through the AJAX calls instead of your PHP code. This example will work:

```
    var currentCounter = 0;
    var countTill = 10;

    function invokeCounter()
    {
        $.ajax({url:"counter.php?counter="+currentCounter,success:function(result)
        {
            $("#div1").html(result);

            if(currentCounter >= countTill)
            {
                clearInterval(myCounter);
            }

            currentCounter++;

        }});
    }

    var myCounter = setInterval(function()
    {
        invokeCounter();
    }, 1000);
```

In your PHP you can get the current counter

```
<?php
    echo "<div>" . time() . ": Iteration ".$_GET['counter']."</div>";
?>
```

I think you know this isn't a right solution for a webcounter, but you are probably experimenting/testing something in JQuery/AJAX/PHP.

Comment: Note that the text in `div1` will be overwritten each iteration. If you want to display every line you can use something like `$("#div1").prepend(result);` instead of `$("#div1").html(result);`

Comment: no actually i need counter from php loop.I have php function that reads image from file form folder and process it in loop but during each iteration i want to print them,but some how its not possible with my code.I see this kind of feature in some of wp plugins where it prints process one by one.

Comment: What is your goal with the loop? Do you want to show a progressbar of the uploaded image?

Comment: No i want to show that that file has been processed in loop.in loop i am reading some images form folder and processiong them

Comment: You should read the folder in javascript and send each filename to your PHP script, where it can be processed. Then you can echo each processed file.